Are emails rendered differently when testing email templates vs actually using them?
I have an email template being sent to an email-to-ticket feature of a different system. I can assign the owner of that ticket in that system by including certain text in the body of the email - !!Assign:firstname.lastname!!
The feature does not work if the email is text-based - the !!Assign text remains visible in the body and has no effect on the ticket owner. We found html templates worked, as do VisualForce templates. We're using the VisualForce template.
In the email template, when I click 'Send Test and Verify Merge Fields' the test email opens the ticket and assigns the user as intended - the !!Assign text is omitted from the ticket. But when I fire that same email alert from the same test record using flow, the !!Assign text stays visible in the body and has no effect on who is assigned - just like when we tested using a 'text' email template from Salesforce.
So here's the question: Are emails rendered differently somehow when testing vs actually sending a Visualforce email template?
Thanks.
